# How to add and subtract value from previous rows based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with values

```
Slno Type     Amount        
 1    P         40           
 2    C         20           
 3    P         45           
 4    P         20           
 5    C         10
```

I want to get values for RESULT column.

```
   Type      Amount       RESULT 
    P         40           40
    C         20           20
    P         45           65
    P         20           85
    C         10           75
```

If Type is C then value gets subtracted from previous value, 
else if Type is P then value gets added to previous values.

This is what i've tried:

```
;WITH FINALMIDRESULT 
     AS (SELECT Type, 
                Value1, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    ORDER BY Slno ASC) rownum 
         FROM   #midRes) 
SELECT C1.Type, 
       C1.Value1, 
       CASE 
         WHEN C1.Type = 'C' THEN (SELECT Sum(Amount) 
                                  FROM   FINALMIDRESULT c2 
                                  WHERE  c2.rownum <= C1.rownum) 
         ELSE (SELECT Sum(Amount) - Sum(Amount) 
               FROM   FINALMIDRESULT c2 
               WHERE  c2.rownum <= C1.rownum) 
       END AS RESULT 
FROM   FINALMIDRESULT C1
```

This is the Result that i have got

```
  Type      Amount       RESULT 
    P         40           0
    C         20           60
    P         45           0
    P         20           0
    C         10           135
```

Comment: What is the "previous value"? A table has no inherent order. So what column(s) do you want to use for ordering? What have you tried?

Comment: ;WITH FINALMIDRESULT AS
(
 select 
 Type,Value1,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Slno asc) rownum from #midRes
)




Select 
C1.Type,C1.Value1,Case when C1.Type='C' then 
 (SELECT SUM(Amount)  FROM FINALMIDRESULT c2 WHERE c2.rownum <= C1.rownum) 
else
(SELECT SUM(Amount)-Sum(Amount) FROM FINALMIDRESULT c2 WHERE c2.rownum <= C1.rownum) 
 end as RESULT

 from FINALMIDRESULT C1

Comment: Which version of sql-server are you using? Tag it. What is wrong with your current approach, wrong result, error? Why don't you show the column `Slno` which is used for the ordering in your sample?

Comment: Can you plz share the expected output? it will be helpful in analysing.

Comment: RESULT Column is Expected Out put...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a seft INNER JOIN to sum all values with `Slno` less than the current value, like below:

```
;WITH   OriginalData    AS
(       SELECT  *
        FROM
        (       VALUES
                (1, 'P', 40),
                (2, 'C', 20),
                (3, 'P', 45),
                (4, 'P', 20),
                (5, 'C', 10)
        )       AS Temp(Slno, Type, Amount)
)
SELECT      [Current].Type, [Current].Amount,
            ISNULL(SUM(
            CASE    WHEN  [Previous].Type = 'P'
                    THEN +[Previous].Amount
                    ELSE -[Previous].Amount
            END),0) + 
            CASE    WHEN  [Current].Type = 'P'
                    THEN +[Current].Amount
                    ELSE -[Current].Amount
            END Result
 FROM       OriginalData [Current]
 LEFT JOIN  OriginalData [Previous]
        ON  [Previous].Slno < [Current].Slno
GROUP BY    [Current].Slno, [Current].Type, [Current].Amount
ORDER BY    [Current].Slno
```

I think the biggest change you can make is to shift your mindset. When you think "previous values" you chose a procedural path which can be solved my any major programming language, but rapidly evolve to a cursor approach in SQL -- what isn't appropriate in this case.

When comes to SQL, you need to think in "sets", so you can drive your efforts to identify those data sets and combine them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SlNo, Type, Amount, 
    Sum((Case when  Type='C' then -1 else 1 END)*Amount) Over(Order by SlNo)  Result
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.