# Used data from the previous record to calculate data of the current one

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

What is the LAG and LEAD syntax for AS400?
I am trying to do some calculation to the current record based on the previous record?

For example:
I need to calculate the Work Center Quantity for each record based on the previous one.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

It is important, as I described in the example, that the calculation will be based on the previous row but not on a total of all the previous rows. I just gave a very optimized example of my needs but actually substracting the SUM of all the previous records is not helping me. Is there a way to subscribe only the previous record?

Comment: Is there a way of order in the data or a primary key which can be used to identify the previous record?

Comment: I guess, this is almost similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066074/how-to-add-and-subtract-value-from-previous-rows-based-on-condition

Comment: @AT-2016, this is for sql server. Not sure, if it will work for me.

Comment: @ehh Why on earth did you label the question with DB2 then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, DB2 is DB2/400 isn't it?

Comment: @ehh Maybe I'm woefully ignorant here, but I thought DB2 was an IBM database, and SQL Server a Microsoft one.  In any case, I gave you a generic answer which should work on both, have a look below.

Comment: For most IBM i (formerly AS/400 or iSeries) shops, sequential record-by-record processing is done using RPG rather than SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following, a very close likeness to my reply to [DB2 recursive UDF Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683650/db2-recursive-udf-table) but with this reply I made almost no review except of the results from a test with the given sample data [plus a column for visually expressing equivalence to expected output] to verify:

Setup:

```
set current schema <whatever>
create table wc
( work_center    for wc       char     
, total_quantity for tq       dec      
, scrap_quantity for sq       dec      
, vfy_quantity   for vq       dec
) 
;
insert into  wc       values     
  ( 'A' ,   1000,     10,   990 )
, ( 'B' ,   1000,      5,   985 )
, ( 'C' ,   1000,     12,   973 )
, ( 'D' ,   1000,      1,   972 )
;
```

Query and result:

```
with
  ordRows (rn, wc, tq, sq, vq) as
   ( select row_number() over(order by wc) as rn
          ,    wc, tq, sq, vq 
     from wc
   )    
, subRows (rn, wc, tq, sq, vq, cq /* calc qty */) as
   ( select rn, wc, tq, sq, vq
          , ( tq - sq )
     from ordRows
     where rn = 1
   union all
     select b.rn, b.wc, b.tq, b.sq, b.vq        
          , ( a.cq - b.sq )
     from subRows a
     join ordRows b
       on a.rn = ( b.rn - 1 )
   )
select dec(rn, 5) as rn, wc, tq, sq
     , vq, ' = ' as eq, cq
from subrows
; -- likeness of report from above query:
....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+
    RN   WC      TQ       SQ       VQ   EQ          CQ 
     1   A    1,000       10      990    =         990 
     2   B    1,000        5      985    =         985 
     3   C    1,000       12      973    =         973 
     4   D    1,000        1      972    =         972 
********  End of data  ********
```

Comment: Getting "SQL0206 - Column VQ not in specified tables." error

Comment: Odd. That script is functional for me on each of IBM i 6.1, 7.1, 7.3. The syntax, IIRC, should be supported since v5r4, but I do not have access to that release nor IBM i 7.2 [aka v7r2]. I do not see any mention of the code level being used; per having called the server an *AS400* in the OP, I suppose most likely, the oldest of those? :-(

Comment: I had created the table in a wrong way (sorry for that). I tried again and it works like a charm. Great!

Comment: let say that I am adding a new column of items where each item has A, B, C and D work center. In this case, the row_number is not being reset to 1 for each item and this mismatching the results. How can I amke the row_number to be reset to 1 for each new item?

Comment: May not have time, nor do I understand the new scenario. Perhaps start a new question offering a script [in text, not image] of both DDL and an INSERT of sample data, along with expected results [text or image, no matter] and an accompanying description of the scenario to help a reader understand the purpose for getting from the data to the results; sufficient[ly diverse] data to avoid ambiguity. With all that, I expect somebody should be able to provide the means. Note: Please include the DB2 platform&release info in any OP; e.g. IBM i version.release information per DB2 for IBM i being used.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking to calculate a running total, which `LAG` and `LEAD` won't necessarily help you accomplish.  One way to compute a running total is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       t1.total_quantity - (SELECT SUM(t2.scrap_quantity)
                            FROM yourTable t2
                            WHERE t2.work_center <= t1.work_center) AS work_center_quantity
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY t1.work_center
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use the proper name of the platform and you'll be far more likely to find current reference material.  IBM i documentation is in the [Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i).

Second, there are three families of DB2.  The IBM i family doesn't have LEAD and LAG yet.  (The other families are LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows), and DB2 for z - mainframes).

The request is a little unusual in that SQL set processing tends to be focussed on sets rather than relative record numbers.  As a result, a recursive CTE can't be used because there's no simple parent/child relationship.  However, brute force can be applied.

```
create table so (
  WorkCenter char(5),
  TotalQuantity decimal(7, 0),
  ScrapQuantity decimal(7, 0),
  WorkCenterQuantity decimal(7, 0)
  );

insert into so values ('A', 1000, 10, 990);
insert into so values ('B', 1000, 5, 985);
insert into so values ('C', 1000, 12, 973);
insert into so values ('D', 1000, 1, 972);

select 1 as level, WorkCenter, TotalQuantity, ScrapQuantity, WorkCenterQuantity, TotalQuantity - ScrapQuantity as newQUantity
from so
where rrn(so) = 1
 union all
select rrn(o) as level, o.WorkCenter, o.TotalQuantity, o.ScrapQuantity, o.WorkCenterQuantity, 
  (select i.WorkCenterQuantity
   from so i
   where rrn(i) = rrn(o) - 1) - o.ScrapQuantity as NewWorkCenterQuantity
from so o
where rrn(o) > 1
order by 1;
```

The idea is to grab the first row, which calculates with columns from the current row, and UNION that to the follow-on rows, which use calculations using both the current and previous row.

*EDIT* Assume WorkCenterQuantity is zero.  Use @Tim's running total in the calculations.

```
update so
set WorkCenterQuantity = 0;

update so u
set WorkCenterQuantity = (
  select NewWorkCenterQuantity 
  from 
    (select 1 as level, WorkCenter, TotalQuantity, ScrapQuantity, WorkCenterQuantity, TotalQuantity - ScrapQuantity as NewWorkCenterQuantity
     from so
     where rrn(so) = 1 
      union all
     select rrn(o) as level, o.WorkCenter, o.TotalQuantity, o.ScrapQuantity, o.WorkCenterQuantity, 
       (select TotalQuantity
        from so
        where rrn(so) = 1) 
         - 
       (select sum(i.ScrapQuantity)
        from so i
        where rrn(i) <= rrn(o)) as NewWorkCenterQuantity
     from so o
     where rrn(o) > 1
     ) x 
  where u.WorkCenter = x.WorkCenter)
;
```

The idea is to perform the calculations using a running total for rows n+1, but retrieving the initial quantity from row 1.

Comment: WorkCenterQuantity is the column to be calculated. In your create table you add the values to be calculated.

Comment: It really looks like you want @Tim's answer.  The calculation can't be based on the previous row, because the previous row - like all of the rows - will be zero until after the update.  So what you really want is for the calculation to be based on the previous calculation, which is what a running total is.  See edit.

Comment: We are almost there: I am getting A(990), B(972), C(972), D(972). I will also try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 with tmp as (
 select t.*, rownumber() over(order by work_center  ) as rang
 from t)
 select f1.*, 
 ifnull(f2.work_center  , f1.total_quantity ) - f1.scrap_quantity 
 AS work_center_quantity 
 from tmp f1 left outer join tmp f2
 on f1.rang-1=f2.rang
```

Comment: It is a good start but it is not working. i am trying to make it works. Only the first record got the value the other are empty

Comment: After some investigation on your suggestion, I found that it doesn't taking in consideration the previous calculated work_center_quantity. The ideal was to replace the "ifnull..." with "ifnull(f2.work_center_quantity, f1.total_quantity) - f1.scrap_quantity AS work_center_quantity" but "work_center_quantity" doesn't exist in the table. Is there a way to achieve the "ideal" solution

Answer (score 0):

Try it :)

```
 with tmp as (
 select t.*, rownumber() over(order by work_center  ) as rang
 from t)
 select f1.*, 
 f1.total_quantity - f3.sum_scrap_quantity    
 AS work_center_quantity 
 from tmp f1 
 inner join lateral
 (
  select sum(f2.scrap_quantity ) sum_scrap_quantity     tmp f2
  where f2.rang<=f1.rang
  ) f3 on 1=1
```